# How do I connect to the Internet? 

Tags: 12.04, internet, internet-connection

I just installed Ubuntu. How can I make an internet connection?

When I start Firefox, the response is

> Server not found.

I have a BSNL broadband connection in India via my telephone line and a ADSL modem.

Comment: is it modem or adsl router? Ok  tell me how you connect in windows. Does it connect automatically or you dial a connection and with userid and password?

Comment: You need to mention the ADSL Modem Model number and Manufacturer's Name. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The BSNL helpline and staff are generally familiar with MS Windows and may not be too helpful but if they are, it will be a pleasant surprise.

I'm assuming that: the modem is an **ADSL router**; you are dual booting with MS Windows; and you have no problem connecting via MS Windows.

- Click on the network manager icon in the top right corner of your
  screen.
- Choose "edit connections" from the drop-down menu.
- Click on "DSL" and then on "add". (You maybe prompted to provide your Ubuntu login password at this or some point.) You can give the connection a name other than DSL1 connection, if you wish.
- Enter your user ID and password and "available to all users".

That should do it. If you are not on an unlimited plan, you may not want to connect "automatically".

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), type `sudo pppoeconf`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then a window will appear with a bar--it's checking your Internet connection.

If your connection is working properly it will ask you some questions. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on every question for "yes." In between it will ask your connection's username and password.

Once you've done this, every time you boot your Ubuntu system it will automatically connect to the Internet.