# Problem with wired internet connecting on MTNL Triband

Tags: 12.04, internet, connection

I am a Ubuntu user from Mumbai, India and subscribe to MTNL's Triband broadband service. I have a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I am getting good internet connectivity when working on Windows 7 but on Ubuntu, even though the 'up and down arrow' denoting a working ethernet connection is seen in the menu, I am unable to access any of the websites or perform any Ubuntu updates using the Terminal. In Windows, connection is automatic without requiring any username or password. Based on some searching that I did here, I found a few commands whose output helps identify the problem. I am posting the output of three of those in the following lines:-

1) lshw

```
pratik@Eureka:~$ sudo lshw

eureka                    
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 1874MiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD Athlon(tm) II X3 440 Processor
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep     mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save cpufreq
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
      product: RS690 Host Bridge
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 66MHz
      configuration: latency=32
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (Internal gfx)
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         resources: ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fde00000-fdffffff ioport:d8000000(size=134217728)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: Radeon 2100
            vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
            physical id: 5
            bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=radeon latency=32
            resources: irq:18 memory:d8000000-dfffffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fde00000-fdefffff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 2)
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 6
         bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:40 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fdd00000-fddfffff ioport:fda00000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: eth0
            version: 03
            serial: 6c:f0:49:dd:10:69
            size: 100Mbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw ip=192.168.1.33 latency=0 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
            resources: irq:41 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fdaff000-fdafffff memory:fdaf8000-fdafbfff memory:fda00000-fda1ffff
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 11
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
         logical name: scsi1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=32
         resources: irq:22 ioport:ff00(size=8) ioport:fe00(size=4) ioport:fd00(size=8) ioport:fc00(size=4) ioport:fb00(size=16) memory:fe02f000-fe02f3ff
       *-cdrom
            description: DVD-RAM writer
            product: BAER DH-24AAS
            vendor: MOSER
            physical id: 0.0.0
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
            logical name: /dev/cdrw
            logical name: /dev/dvd
            logical name: /dev/dvdrw
            logical name: /dev/sr0
            version: BM7Z
            capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
            configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 12
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:16 memory:fe02e000-fe02efff
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 12.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:16 memory:fe02d000-fe02dfff
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 12.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:fe02c000-fe02c0ff
    *-usb:3
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 13
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fe02b000-fe02bfff
    *-usb:4
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 13.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fe02a000-fe02afff
    *-usb:5
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 13.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:19 memory:fe029000-fe0290ff
    *-serial
         description: SMBus
         product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 3c
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: cap_list
         configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-ide
         description: IDE interface
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 14.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ide bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=32
         resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:fa00(size=16)
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 14.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
         version: 00
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: irq:16 memory:fe024000-fe027fff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 14.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 14.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master vga_palette
         resources: ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:fdc00000-fdcfffff memory:fdb00000-fdbfffff
    *-usb:6
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 14.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fe028000-fe028fff
 *-pci:1
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 101
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:2
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 10h Processor Address Map
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 102
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:3
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 103
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:4
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 104
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=k10temp
      resources: irq:0
 *-pci:5
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 10h Processor Link Control
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 105
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
  *-scsi
   physical id: 1
   bus info: scsi@4
   logical name: scsi4
   capabilities: scsi-host
   configuration: driver=usb-storage
```

2)lspci

```
pratik@Eureka:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS690 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (Internal gfx)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 2)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Radeon 2100
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
```

3) ifconfig eth0

```
pratik@Eureka:~$ ifconfig eth0:
eth0:     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:dd:10:69  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Interrupt:41
```

I hope this is not a repost of a question already posted on this forum. If it is, I apologize for the same.

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Thanks!

Comment: See if this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/134338/25656) helps. It's for BSNL.

Comment: @vasa1 thanks for the suggestion. I tried the first two answers in the link you referred to but neither worked for me. I created a new DSL connection but still am not able to access any websites. And the result of `sudo pppoeconf` can be seen in the screenshot ![here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/67s8f). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing problem in installing MTNL data card '3G Jadoo'. I tried using Tata photon. It automatically get installed in Ubuntu 12.10. I clicked on networking logo on top right hand corner and was able to surf web.